# How to prevent multiple location notifications from being triggered

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification, geofencing

I have multiple location notifications registered, often they overlap with each other. I want to limit to one fired notification per day, but the problem is that I do not have any way to cancel all the pending notifications when app is killed and can only do it when BGAppRefreshTaskRequest is triggered (which is not a common thing most of the times). And the worst part is that if user is in overlapping area he'll receive multiple push notifications at once.

Code to register notification:

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Title"
content.body = "Body"
content.sound = .default
content.userInfo = ["locationNotificationId" : id]
content.categoryIdentifier = "geofenceNotifications"

let region = CLCircularRegion(center: location,
                              radius: CLLocationDistance(range),
                              identifier: id)
region.notifyOnEntry = true
region.notifyOnExit = false
let trigger = UNLocationNotificationTrigger(region: region, repeats: false)

let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: id,
                                    content: content,
                                    trigger: trigger)

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    }
})
```

What do I do to prevent other notifications being triggered after one is fired if app is in the background or killed?

Comment: you can cancel notification this way removeAllPendingNotificationRequests() or removeAllDeliveredNotifications()

Comment: befoure you schedule check if any pending notification available then don't schedule other one

Comment: @lali I could remove it using removeAllPendingNotificationRequests, but only if it's in foreground, otherwise I have no way to call this function

Comment: @SPatel the problem is not the scheduling itself, the problem is not being able to remove all the scheduled ones after one is fired if app is in the background or killed.

Comment: But why you schedule others

Comment: @SPatel I have multiple locations across the city and need to fire notification when user comes to any of those places, but only for the first location, whichever it happens to be.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I managed to resolve the issue by monitoring region itself instead of using local push notification with UNLocationNotificationTrigger. The downsides are - I need to ask location access for background instead of "when in use" and I'm limited to 20 regions but it still better than uncontrolled flow of push notifications.

To read more about region monitoring: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5470-geofencing-with-core-location-getting-started#toc-anchor-004